# Java TCP file transfer application

Tags: java, file, tcp, udp, client-server

Hello and thanks in advance for taking the time to read. I'm trying to develop a simple Java file transfer application using TCP. So far using my client and server classes I've managed to add a working upload method to it (upload a file to the computer where the server's running).

I'm quite inexperienced with this yet so I'm going rather slowly. I also need to add a download option (get a file from the server), list all the files from the server, and also an option that allows me to delete any file from the server.

For both the server and the client I'm using a specific default folder (C:/Sharedfolder in this case). Currently my questions are:

1. In my current server code, files that are uploaded to it are renamed to "newfile". How can I make it change the filename to something like "oldfile_new" (being oldfile the actual original file's name)?
2. Using my current server code below, can I make a client class for downloading a file from the server that will work with it? And how do I do that? The uploading part made sense to me, but I'm still trying to figure out the downloading/listing files from the server.
3. I'm currently using a predefined host IP, but I'll eventually need to modify the application so that the client sends out a UDP broadcast to find the server on a private network. Can anyone point me on any direction on how to do this?

My current server code is as follows:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4555);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Can't setup server on this port number.\n");
    }

    Socket socket = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    int bufferSize = 0;
    System.out.println("Ready...");

    try {
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Can't accept client connection.\n");
    }

    try {
        is = socket.getInputStream();

        bufferSize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
        System.out.println("Buffer size: " + bufferSize);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Can't get socket input stream.\n");
    }

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Sharedfolder\\newfile");
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found.\n");
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

    int count;

    while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }

    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    is.close();
    socket.close();
    serverSocket.close();

}
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to a BufferedInput/OutputStream if you are already reading/writing large byte[].  A download is the same as a upload, the only difference is which end is sending and which end is receiving.  The code is basically the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will the download part require me to add something to the server class though? Or will changes be done client side only? What confuses me is the server being running on the background.

Comment: The only difference between the client and the server is who created the connection, after that you have a Socket which looks the same at both ends.  I suggest you extract code to send a file and another method to receive a file.  The difference is that the server will be sending instead of the client and the client will be receiving instead of sending.  The fact the process is running in the background shouldn't make any difference.  The client could be in the background too.

Comment: Yes, my issue here is (and I'm sorry if this is too blatantly obvious though I'm still trying to understand) how to make the server KNOW that I want to get a file from it, through the client. Upon sending a request, how will the server know I'm requesting a file from it? Because at least to me it seems that the current code only allows the server to receive files.

Comment: You are right, you would have to change the code.  A common approach is for the client to first send the server a command.  There are any number of ways to do this.  Based on the command, the server can send a file of a given name, receive a file or something else like disconnect.

Comment: That does make sense. How would I be able to send a command? Through the output from [is = socket.getInputStream()]? I'll attempt something with this, thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming exercise?  What about ssh/scp, sftp, rsync, etc.  There are Java implementations of clients and servers for all these protocols.  There is no reason to reinvent this wheel unless none of the well-tested free implementations work for you.

Comment: When you get an exception, print or log the exception. Don't substitute an arbitrary message of your own devising. It makes proper debugging impossible.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools that already do this, but its a good learning exercise.

Generally you need to not only transfer the data but also some information about the file itself:

1. Send the file's name from server to client
2. Send the file's size from server to client
3. Send the file's data to the client. The client can use the size received in step to to calculate progress
4. Send the file's mod time from server to client. CLient stamps the received file with the mod time

All of these things can be sent over the stream objects you have instantiated, you just have to be sure that the sequence of events between client/server are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use java to construct a client-server safe file transfer channel using encryption ,certificate.So ,maybe I can give you some help.

**question 1**:For getting the file name from the client side ,you have to transfer the filename to server ahead of transferring the file data.

**question 2**:For download the file from server, you have to give a signal(a file download /upload request) to your server to tell it whether it is a download or a upload operation,looks very like ftp protocol .Such a signal should  be pre-tranferred to the server side.So ,you have to open a same socket as the server side which is used to get inputStream of the file from the server.

```
public static boolean send(FileInputStream fis,OutputStream os) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
     while(true)
        {
            int read=0;
        if(fis!=null)
            read=fis.read(buf);
        byte[] result=new byte[read];
        //System.out.println(read);
        // os.write(buf,0,read);

         System.arraycopy(buf, 0, result,0, read);
            os.write(result);
            if(read < BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                //System.out.println("服务器向客户端发送read="+read);
            break;
            }
        }//while
    fis.close();    
    return true;
}
```

in the function ,fis is the the file stream which is to be sent . os is the output stream which is get from the socket like:

```
s = new ServerSocket(6868);
socket= s.accept();
os=socket.getOutputStream();
```

**question 3**:You should the set the ip address, port number and protocol type(TCP/UDP) as arguments of your main function.So ,you can just set your arguments,not modify your source code ,to make your application run in different direction as you want.

That is just what I know.Hope that it can give you some help.